# Bootstrap, required="true" not supported in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
     <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="True" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: My question was that in html5 if I am passing required="true" in input  than also it is not giving validation. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native form validation was not implemented until IE10. `required` is an HTML attribute and not an attribute added by Bootstrap, and Bootstrap does not implement form validation.

If you'd like form validation in IE9, you'll need to add a JavaScript library.

Browser support for form validation: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation